# Why does PsGetCurrentProcessId() return null?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, windbg, pid

I run into a weird problem:

In a thread of the 'system' process, I called `PsGetCurrentProcessId()`, but got a null value.

Moreover, I checked the thread's _CLIENT_ID, and found both UniqueProcess and UniqueThread were null.

I also checked the current process, i.e. the 'system' process, and found its UniqueProcessId was 4 which is normal.

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "I also checked the current process", i.e., what system calls did you use to do so?  Also, where did the thread in question come from, i.e., what context are you in when you call PsGetCurrentProcessId?

Comment: I check those with WinDBG.

Comment: How did you determine that the "current process" for that thread was the system process?

Comment: @Harry, through  WinDBG commands: .process and !process

Comment: OK, there are two questions here: why is the current process ID (as returned by _CLIENT_ID and PsGetCurrentProcessId) zero, and why does WinDBG still show it as 4?  I suspect that the answer to the first question is that system threads are a special case.  For example, it might be that all kernel-only threads have ID zero, and only user-mode system threads have ID 4.  As for the second question, I don't know, but it may just be an oddity of WinDBG.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are experiencing?  Why are you calling PsGetCurrentProcessId in the first place?

Comment: @Harry, I wanted to get the process id, and though the id to query process token information. If the process id is not valid, then the query will fail. This is my initial problem.

Comment: It seems to me that querying the processes token information only makes sense when a user process is involved, which doesn't seem to be the case here.  Perhaps you're doing the query from the wrong context, i.e., not within a driver function that is guaranteed to be running in a user thread?

Answer (score 2):

The system process ID is a very nice "hack" so that multiple tools (such as ProcExp, windbg) don't have to special case kernel-only threads or the idle function dispatcher.

If you're a kernel only thread, you don't have an associated process (unless you attack yourself to one).